# Console.log comparison with number

Tags: javascript

I'm on Lesson 28/28 of Getting Started with Programming of Codeacademy's Javascript tutorial. I want to create a program in which a prompt comes up where I enter a quantity and if the quantity is

```
var numberOfLessons = prompt("How many lessons have you taken?")

if(numberOfLessons===28)
{
    console.log("I finished my first course!")
}

else if(numberOfLessons<28)
{
    console.log("Do more lessons!")
}
else if(numberOfLessons>28)
{
    console.log("Do less lessons D:")
}
```

When I run the program, if I input a quantity less than 28, then the proper "Do more lessons!" comes up. However, with ===, if I input 28, then console.log doesn't output anything. It's completely blank. However, if I use == in line 3, instead of ===, then inputting "28" into the prompt returns the proper "I finished my first course!"

```
var numberOfLessons = prompt("How many lessons have you taken?")

if(numberOfLessons===28)
{
    console.log("I finished my first course!")
}

else if(numberOfLessons<28)
{
    console.log("Do more lessons!")
}

else if(numberOfLessons>28)
{
    console.log("Do less lessons D:")
}
```

Why is it that == works but === doesn't? My first thought (or, rather, my friend's first thought) was that it's because numberOfLessons is a variable and === requires the types of the two things being compared to be the same, and a variable is not the same as a number. But, in that case, why would it work for the "else if" statement where > is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `console.prompt()` returns a string. Since the `===` operator returns false if the values are diffent types, the condition is false because you're comparing a string and a number. If you use `==`, then the condition will be true because it converts the string to a number and compares.

Answer (score 1):

The identity `(===)` operator behaves identically to the equality `(==)` operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

I guess your input you are taking from user must be in form of string and you are comparing it to a number thus `(===)` fails.

To prove my point i changed `numberOfLessons===28` to `numberOfLessons==="28"` which returns true. Thus proving numberOfLessons is a string and thus type were not equal

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/5VdWW/

Comment: This makes sense. Does that mean that > and < do type conversion?

Comment: Yup, as you noticed it yourself. Hope the answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

The `===` compares value and type, it will work if you change to `==="28"`, because the var `numberOfLessons` is of **string** type.

The `==` compare only the value, that is why it works.

You can check [this refence](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more details about it.